# How to access WidgetCenter from WidgetKit in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, widgetkit

I need to notify `WidgetKit` to reload my iOS 14 widget. In Swift you can do that using [WidgetCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter):

```swift
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

However, `WidgetKit` seems to be unavailable in Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios14/#embedded-widgetkit-support

Comment: @Jason How this answers the question? This about adding iOS 14 widget which I already have. Not about accessing `WidgetCenter` from `Xamarin.iOS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WidgetKit's `reloadAllTimelines` is not currently available to Xamarin.iOS (it is available only via the Swift-based frameworks and technically Xamarin.iOS binds the ObjC frameworks).

It is on the Xamarin.iOS enhancement list

- [[Xcode 12] WidgetKit reloadTimelines API is Swift only but really needs to be callable from C# host app #9215](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9215)

Currently you would need to write a Swift library and then Xamarin.iOS bind it to expose it so you can call it from .Net code.

- [Bind iOS Swift libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/)
- [[xcode12] WidgetKit #8933](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8933)

---

Third-party repo/project that exposes WidgetKit's `ReloadTimeLinesOfKind`, `ReloadAllTimeLines`, & `GetCurrentConfigurationsWithCompletion` (see  Wojciech Kulik's comment below)

Comment: Thank you, following your links I have found this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8931 and one guy already implemented this proxy library: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8931#issuecomment-701357996 I tried it and it works with small modifications which I described there!

Comment: @WojciechKulik Thanks for the #8931 link that links to https://github.com/Csaba8472/WidgetCenterProxy  The `ApiDefinitions.cs` is exactly what I pictured, I'm not sure why Xamarin does not just generate the Swift definitions and auto-include the Swift-based framework references if the user's code references them...